# CLI command to switch off Redis cache

Tags: magento2, cli, redis, deploy

There is CLI command to [set up Redis](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html) as backend for Magento cache:

```
$ ./bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis
```

Does any CLI command exist to switch off Redis as cache backend for Magento?

Comment: You tried bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=db or bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=database ?

Comment: I've tried `--cache-backend=db` with error result

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, As far as I know core team did not had insight of implementing this, you can check the class implementing it to see if it is otherwise -  `Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigOptionsList\Cache` .

Your best bet would be removing the cache node from env.php where child has value "Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis" and clearing config cache.